# How to modify the wazuh-dashboard website if wazuh-indexer, server, and dashboard are installed on VM(fedora)?

Tags: linux, plugins, wazuh

If we have installed wazuh indexer, wazuh-server, and wazuh-dashboard on a VM (example: fedora) and we want to now change the website or wazuh-dashboaboad, then does it mean we have to clone the wazuh-kibana-app git repository on our local device?

If that is the way to change the website content, than how will this kibana-app repository changes mounted on the wazuh installed on fedora so that we can see the changes made on the content of website?

I tried to install all three wazuh indexer, server and dashboard on a VM and as a result the website was clearly visible when we started the services by typing the command:

```
systemctl start wazuh-dashboard.
```

Now I want to change the content of website which are visible, so I cloned the wazuh-Kibana-app on my local machine and did some changes that I wanted to implant. How can I apply these changes into the wazuh that is installed in the VM server?

Answer (score 0):

It's important to clarify the various subcomponents involved in order to determine how to perform the modifications you're interested in.

The Wazuh Dashboard is a repackaging of the OpenSearch Dashboard project. This repackaging is done to improve the user experience by having a unique version guaranteed to be compatible between all components (manager/server, agents, indexer and dashboard), to include built-in modifications to the configuration and to include the Wazuh Dashboard plugin out of the box. It is this plugin that is developed and maintained in the [wazuh-kibana-app](https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh-kibana-app) repository.

If you wish to do simple changes such as changing the branding, then you can do so through changes to the configuration as explained on [the documentation regarding custom branding](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/wazuh-dashboard/custom-branding.html).

If you wish to create a custom dashboard you may easily do so without having to modify the code thanks to the Dashboards application. You may find good documentation for this [here in the documentation of the OpenSearch project](https://opensearch.org/docs/2.4/dashboards/dashboard/index/).

Finally, if you wish to modify the Wazuh plugin, you can clone the [wazuh-kibana-app](https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh-kibana-app) plugin and compile it following [these instructions available in the repository's wiki](https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh-kibana-app/wiki/Build-Wazuh-app-package). Note that these instructions, as well as the repository's name, have not been updated since we've migrated from Kibana, so the file paths will vary where the Wazuh plugin folder is now `/usr/share/wazuh-dashboard/plugins/wazuh/`.